# Adding pyqtgraph to PyQt6

Tags: pyqtgraph, pyqt6

> So I am making a GUI using Pyqt6 and want to add graphs inside the Gui with other data, SO when I try adding the graph i get the error bellow:

call:   addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PlotWidget'   addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, alignment: Qt.AlignmentFlag = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PlotWidget'   addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, int, int, alignment: Qt.AlignmentFlag = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PlotWidget'

The code I have

```
    self.plt=pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()
    self.plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])
    grid.addWidget(self.plt, 6, 1, 3, 3)
    self.setLayout(grid)  #up I have grid=QGridLayout()
```

Comment: It would help too see minimal working example with imports as well. Also which version of  pyqtgraph You are using. You can try to upgrade it to newest version with `python3 -m pip install pyqtgraph --upgrade`

Comment: @Domarm I upgraded but it doesn't show anything different, still getting the same error.

Comment: @Ahmed please add a valid [mre] including the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to reproduce Your issue for a while.
I succeeded after I install PyQt5 and PyQt6 together in the same environment.

As @musicamante pointed out, it's important to first import PyQt6 and ONLY after that pyqtgraph.
Otherwise [QT_LIB](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/8279a0adb8954a21d5285e0a579d8101e01a6e45/pyqtgraph/Qt/__init__.py#L36) is not set properly and only guesses PyQt version from already installed packages in the environment.

Comment: This is probably due to the way pyqtgraph "guesses" the backend, which can be restricted by the proper import statements (which we asked to the OP, but were never provided). In which order did you import those libraries?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Well, he didn't have to import PyQt5. It was enough to have it installed in the environment. So even valid minimal example would not help in this case.

Comment: Having both versions should *never* be an issue, and importing PyQt *first* should solve the problem as pyqtgraph is normally able to properly detect the already imported Qt binding on its own. Otherwise, it must be reported to the project as a possible bug.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I dig up a bit and found out QT_LIB constant, which detects  PyQt version. For installation with both PyQt5 and 6, it yields `PyQt5`.

Comment: And importing PyQt6 *before* pyqtgraph solves the problem?

Comment: Yup, it's as You said. PyQt must be imported before pyqtgraph. If it's like that QT_LIB is set properly. Even I had it wrong and imported pyqtgraph before PyQt. At least I was able to reproduce @Ahmeds problem :)